# is there a way to set coloring for cd tab complete?

Tags: bash, zsh, colors, autocomplete

I use ubuntu 11.04.

Is there a way to set coloring for output after tab completion listing of a cd, ls, or etc. ?

i.e.

`myshell@root$ cd ~/user/files/` I hit tab...

*myfile* myfoo  mybar <--  this output is colored?

I hope you enjoyed my diagram.

Comment: What exactly should be colored?  Do you want files to be colored the same as `ls --color` would do?  Do you want the first one to be colored, then when you press Tab again, the second one to be colored, etc?  Something else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With readline 6.3 and later you can add

```
set colored-stats on
```

to `~/.inputrc`.

See https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html:

> `colored-stats`
>
> If set to ``on`', Readline displays possible completions using different colors to indicate their file type. The color definitions are taken from the value of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable. The default is ``off`'.

You can use http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/ to generate both `LS_COLORS` (which is used by GNU `ls` and `colored-stats`) and `LSCOLORS‏` (which is used by BSD `ls`).

Comment: Also see the option `visible-stats`.

Comment: you may have to `$if Bash\nset colored-stats on\n$endif` to avoid bugs with other programs that don't understand the new readline functions.

Comment: Not working for me on MacOS Mojave 10.14.4. My bash --version is `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)`

Comment: Works for me. I use https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized/blob/master/dircolors.ansi-light and just commented out `SOCK 35;44` to work better with my light themed terminal.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if it is in bash (the default shell). It is possible in [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) (a more powerful shell than bash, available on most unices including [Ubuntu](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/zsh) but often not installed by default).

The first time you run zsh, it will offer to create a configuration file (`~/.zshrc`) for you. The default configuration is a bit barren, for historical compatibility. For colored completion listings, select `2` to configure the “new completion system”, then `2` again to tune it; in the `compinstall` menu, select `3` to set styles for displaying completions and `3` then `1` to enable colored completions and finally `2` to use the same colors as `ls`.

If you prefer setting this up by hand, here are the lines you need in your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(@s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

The [`list-colors` style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-list_002dcolors_002c-completion-style) tunes colors on file name completions.