# bash colored completion doesn't obey LS_COLORS environment variable

Tags: bash, terminal, ls, colors

In bash, I have colored output set up for commands such as `ls`. I customized the exact colors used with the `LS_COLORS` environment variable, since the default ones were kind of ugly.

From what I understand the `LS_COLORS` variable is also supposed to be used to set the color specs for colored tab completion, but that doesn't seem to work. The colored tab completion continues to use the default color specs.

!!!! I AM NOT ASKING HOW TO GET COLORED COMPLETION !!!!

I already have colored completion by putting `bind 'set colored-stats on'` in my `~/.bashrc` file. I'm asking why the colored completion doesn't obey the customizations set in `LS_COLORS`. Please don't mark me as a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/251107/how-to-get-a-colored-tab-completion [is there a way to set coloring for cd tab complete?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/is-there-a-way-to-set-coloring-for-cd-tab-complete/133866#133866) or something similar.

See the attached screenshot. The top command is when I run ls. The second is when I type ls and hit tab. I also tried setting `LSCOLORS` environment variable, but no luck. I'm using bash 4.4.19 and my `$TERM` is "xterm-256color" if thats relevant.

[image: different color for ls and tab completion]

edit:

The exact way I'm setting the `LS_COLORS` variable is by having `eval "$(dircolors ~/.dircolors)"` in my `~/.bashrc` file. The `~/.dircolors` is what I customized. This sets my LS_COLOR to the following (which successfully customizes my `ls` output but not tab completion).

```
$ echo $LS_COLORS
rs=0:no=00:fi=00:di=38;5;26:ln=target:mh=04:pi=01;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=01;33:cd=01;33:or=01;31:mi=00;31:su=32;04:sg=92;04:ca=36;04:tw=04;38;5;26:ow=00;38;5;26:st=01;38;5;26:ex=01;32:*.tar=38;5;202:*.tgz=38;5;202:*.arc=38;5;202:*.arj=38;5;202:*.taz=38;5;202:*.lha=38;5;202:*.lz4=38;5;202:*.lzh=38;5;202:*.lzma=38;5;202:*.tlz=38;5;202:*.txz=38;5;202:*.tzo=38;5;202:*.t7z=38;5;202:*.zip=38;5;202:*.z=38;5;202:*.Z=38;5;202:*.dz=38;5;202:*.gz=38;5;202:*.lrz=38;5;202:*.lz=38;5;202:*.lzo=38;5;202:*.xz=38;5;202:*.zst=38;5;202:*.tzst=38;5;202:*.bz2=38;5;202:*.bz=38;5;202:*.tbz=38;5;202:*.tbz2=38;5;202:*.tz=38;5;202:*.deb=38;5;202:*.rpm=38;5;202:*.jar=38;5;202:*.war=38;5;202:*.ear=38;5;202:*.sar=38;5;202:*.rar=38;5;202:*.alz=38;5;202:*.ace=38;5;202:*.zoo=38;5;202:*.cpio=38;5;202:*.7z=38;5;202:*.rz=38;5;202:*.cab=38;5;202:*.wim=38;5;202:*.swm=38;5;202:*.dwm=38;5;202:*.esd=38;5;202:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

Comment: I have `eval "$(dircolors ~/.dircolors)"` in my bashrc that sets LS_COLOR. The exact value is quite long since I have a lot of customizations (I'll edit my question and add it there). The customizations are working for `ls` but not for tab completion. I honestly have no idea what could be wrong or how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Comment: did you export LS_COLORS at all?

Comment: @Cnoor0171 well no the way you call it. OK so now that is the problem. Somehow between eval and dircolors the export gets lost.

Comment: @rastafile the dircolors command puts the export automatically. The export is definitely working, because without it the output of `ls` wouldn't be colored either.

Comment: Well that was my last try. Without any intermediate (debugging) result this is no fun. Starting from that awful mess in the screenshot. This readline-completiion-color is enough tricky already. Who says dircolors exports automaically I tested before. Not gonna go back.

Comment: I just export LS_COLORS without dircolors and eval.

Comment: @rastafile I tried exporting LS_COLORS and even LSCOLORS. the dircolors output already has export but I added another one just because. Same results. Not sure what other debugging results I can give you. What about the screenshot is messy? I can take another one if it helps.

Comment: @Cnoor0171 I am having a very similar issue, did you figure out what was the cause in your case?